# Else statement does not work

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I don't know why my else statement didn't work.

It's my first time that actually happened and I checked using `console.log()`.

This is my code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var b = 2;
  var d = 80000;
  if ("div[class='resultInfo resultLose']") {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var a = ($("input[name='_4']").val().replace(/\s+/g, ''));
      var c = a * b;
      $("input[name='_4']").val(c);
      $("input[value='Play!']").click();
    }, 1000);
  } else if ("div[class='resultInfo resultWin']") {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("input[name='_4']").val(d);
      $("input[value='Play!']").click();
    }, 1000);
  }
}, 4500);
```

I have tried to:

1. delete the `setTimeout` in `if`
2. delete the "`if ("div[class='resultInfo resultWin']")`"

This only uses first `if` even the `elseif` is `true`, I don't know what to do.

Comment: What's `if ("div[class='resultInfo resultLose']")` supposed to do?

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can also click `<>` icon in the header in edit mode to add a demo.

Comment: This if is waiting for result if div[class='resultInfo resultLose'] is existing thene start function in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current if and else/if conditions are just testing the truthiness of a random string which will always evaluate to true. Since the first condition evaluates to true, you will always skip the else if condition (even though that will also evaluate to true in this instance).

What you actually seem to want to test is whether or not there are elements that exist that match the strings you have *as selector strings*. If that's the case, your simplest fix would be to change your if and else statements to look more like jQuery statements and checking the length of the result.

```
if ($("div[class='resultInfo resultLose']").length > 0)
```

and

```
else if ($("div[class='resultInfo resultWin']").length > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i missed $ in it 
The answer was so simple, you're great!

Answer (score 2):

You are having a non-empty string inside your if condition, which evaluates to true every time. So else block will never be reached.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make sense.

You aren't entering the `else if` because your `if` will always evaluate to `true`.

`if ("div[class='resultInfo resultLose']")` will always be `true`, as you're not doing any comparision, you're evaluating a string. So that's the same as doing `if (true)`.

I supose you're missing some code there, like a JQuery selection or something like that.